# Old server name still showing

Tags: sql-server

I renamed SQL instance

```
exec sp_dropserver 'oldname'
go
excec add_linkedserver 'newname'
```

Rebooted server

`select @@servername` shows new server, but, `exec sp_helpserver` shows old and instance names.

In the registry, i updated name under SQL server keys but it didn't change anything

*EDIT*

As soon as i run `sp_dropserver 'oldname', 'droplogins'`

and run `exec sp_helpserver`

it shows only new name but if i run sp_helpserver again, old one appears too in second row

Answer (score 4):

According to your post, you've used sp_addlinkedserver which is not the partner procedure for sp_dropserver. The correct partner is [sp_addserver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-addserver-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16). Please note that depending on the setup, configuration, and feature use, changing the server name may cause unintended side effects.

Comment: sp_addserver is not supported, getting error and sugestion to use sp_addlinkedserver

Comment: How is addserver not supported? That's the proper way. Adding a linked server is incorrect.

Comment: https://nakulvachhrajani.com/2012/05/28/0164-sql-server-2012-discontinued-features-spaddserver-remote-server-registration-msg-15663/

Comment: I'd suggest you read the article, "Replace remote servers by using linked servers." this isn't a REMOTE server.

Answer (score -3):

Run the below query to update the server name in the sys.servers catalog:

```
USE master;
GO

-- Update the server name in sys.servers
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
RECONFIGURE;
EXEC sp_configure 'allow updates', 1;
RECONFIGURE;

UPDATE sys.servers SET data_source = 'newname' WHERE server_id = 0;

-- Turn off the ability to update system catalogs
EXEC sp_configure 'allow updates', 0;
RECONFIGURE;
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 0;
RECONFIGURE;
```

Comment: You should never update or attempt to update any system tables directly.

Comment: ok, what is other solution to my problem ?

Comment: `Ad hoc updates to system catalogs are not allowed` error